# Tree analysis - CHAID cart

Tags: feature-selection, cart

I am new to CHAID and want to know how to decide which independent variables I should select to run CHAID Analyis? Is there a technique to select and then apply them and run the analysis? Please guide me regarding this.

Comment: See the `feature-selection` tag I've just added. It's quite a broad topic.

Comment: are you suggesting stepwise,forward or backward selection techniques to be implemented for selecting significant independent variables before running CHAID?

Comment: Wasn't suggesting anything - just thinking that knowing the name for what you're asking about might help you research it, & that adding the tag would help experts on the topic here notice your question. Note that CHAID won't necessarily use all the independent variables for splitting, so it's already doing a kind of feature selection.